I can't open server in 0.0.0.0 instead it is working in 127.0.0.1 in while using Docker , Django and Postgres
I am a newbie to this.
settings.py file is:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}


Docker file is:
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 
COPY . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]

Docker compose file is:
version: '3.8'

services:
    db:

        image:  postgres
        volumes:
            - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        environment:
            POSTGRES_DB: postgres
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
        container_name: postgres_db
 
    web:
        tty: true
        
        command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        build:  .
        volumes:
            - .:/usr/src/app
        ports:
            -   8000:8000
        container_name: django_container
        
        
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
            POSTGRES_HOST: db
        depends_on:
            - db
            


requirements.txt file is:
Django
psycopg2

docker-compose build
docker-compose up
docker exec -it django-container bash -l
python manage.py migrate 

docker-compose ps
is run  and this is the output:


ml: versionis obsolete" NAME               IMAGE         COMMAND                  SERVICE   CREATED         STATUS          PORTS django_container   airline-web   "python3 manage.py r…"   web       4 minutes ago   Up 48 seconds   0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp postgres_db        postgres      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   db        3 hours ago     Up 48 seconds   5432/tcp


above were run server is running in 127.0.0.1:8000 instead of 0.0.0.0:8000. Am I missing something. I am a newbie to this.

0.0.0.0 is often not adressable, although not standardized https://superuser.com/questions/949428/whats-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-0-0-0-0
